# WPF datepicker issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

Xaml code

```
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,50,0,10" Name="dateText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
      <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource insertTransaction}" Path="Date" />
      </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
    </DatePicker>
```

he code for date property in the above binded(insertTransaction) class

```
private DateTime? date;
    public DateTime? Date 
    {
      get { return this.date; }
      set { this.date = value; }
    }
```

How can i retrieve just the date part and not the whole date and time. Nullable date is mandatory because user might not know the date at first time and may enter it later. DateTime.ToShortDateTime() doesn't work on DateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for this: DateTime has a Property [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx). This only returns the DatePart. However you have to check for nulls before.

**Update**

Based on your comment, I think that you are looking for some information about nullable types. 
Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.90).aspx) msdn-article for further information about nullable types in .net.

DateTime? is a DateTime that is nullable. Because of this, you will get null exceptions if you try to get values from its properties if it is null. Therefore you have first to check if it is null before and the accessing properties or methods such as ToShortDateString().

**There is no .net native type specifically only for Dates**. All dates are handled in the DateTime-structure and have a time-component. You can make your own type or handle with strings (for example DateTime.GetShortDateString returns a string).  Another way to deal with this and also with null values of nullable types is to use a `ValueConverter`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). They are usable from xaml and can handle all you want. They are very powerfull.

Comment: nullable datetime? doesn't have this property.

Comment: Well i am using nullable type of Datetime because in that case, the textbox shows "Select a date" when the DateTime date is null. If i use regular DateTime, it will show 01/01/0001 until i set DateTime = Datetime.Now()
It's very important for me that i enable user to leave the date blank and fill it some other time.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
public DateTime? Date {
    get { return this.date.Value.Date; }
    set { this.date = value; }
}
```

You will also get time which is to be neglected and the dummy one (as 12:00AM something)

If you want exactly date without time, you have to accept it as string `ToShortDateTime();` in `get`.

Comment: What's the use of this if it still carried time string. And that too of no worth ....Now it's 21/12/2010 00:00:00 ... Thats the whole difference

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where you want to retrieve date part in code or in xaml. Anyway in code you can do that like this:

```
if (Date.HasValue == true)
{
    return Date.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what you are suggesting. Well in anycase ToShortDateTime doesn't work on DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all !!
I guess i was heading south instead of north :-P .... Well Now i am going to use the Nullable DateTime? the way it's supposed to be used. Instead of trying to look for improper solution of extracting date, i am going to use StringFormat; whenever i require to display date.

I guess this is the optimum solution. Let me know if you guys think other ways.

Thanks once again